# Is title advancement required for the first baron?

Tags: lord-of-ultima

To recruit my first baron do I need to research a title advancement, or does the first one come "free"?  I'm asking so I know if I need to build a moonglow tower in my first city or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to get a [title advancement to Earl](http://www.lordofultima.com/en/wiki/view/cities) for your second city.